# Strange issue-Redmi note4-not recognised over adb

Tags: android, adb, redmi-device

I have this strange issue on redmi note-4.
My configuation is:
1.Windows 10 pc
2.Android studio latest version(as of writing this issue)
3.Enable USB debugging in the phone

Whenever i open a command prompt & type "adb devices",my redmi note-4 does not show up in the list of devices.

Also in the android studio the device shows as disconnected.

Then i have to go to the phone setting disable/enable usb debugging.
Go to command prompt & type "adb  kill-server"

Then the device again shows up.

Anybody facing this kind of an issue ?

Comment: try to uninstall and install back latest adb driver for that phone

Comment: @androidXP Kindly elaborate on how i can do that ? Do i need to go to devicemanager and uninstall the drivers ?

Answer (score 0):

Download and install this driver 
https://xiaomifirmware.com/download/2696/?dlm-dp-dl-force=1&dlm-dp-dl-nonce=7b894f654a